# ubuntu-drivers is not listing all devices: can I update to recommended driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dependencies

I only see GTX-1060.  There are two other cards missing, both P102-100.  Currently I am running nvidia 470 and the recommended driver is ---

nvidia-driver-525 - third-party non-free recommended

Since the P102-100 is missing does that indicate that 525 will not work?

There is another problem when running "autoinstall" perhaps related:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-nvidia-525-generic : Depends: linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.4.0-136-generic (= 5.4.0-136.153+1) but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-525 (<= 525.60.11-1) but 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: For the dependency problem, check to see if you have ppas installed that contain conflicting versions of drivers.

Comment: OS: Linux Ubuntu: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS [5.4.0-136-generic|libc 2.31]
The drivers for the p102-100 are missing from newer Windows 10 Nvidia releases and I did not want to upgrade to 525 and find the p102 not working in Ubuntu.  They are used only for OpenCL & CUDA

Comment: I found that 515 installed just fine and that 525 really benefits much newer RTX boards that I do not have.